# Ways to have a p element to dynamically fill (via text-size) parent div

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a p element with a large body of text (multi-line) and I want it to fill a parent div automatically: the text needs to should fill the parent with as few lines as possible while keeping the text easy to read. The best way to do this, as far as I can see, is to have it change font-size.

I've tried multiple "fit text" js plugins but I cant get any of them to work for multi-line paragraphs.

I think this would be possible though the use of several CSS media queries But I want to know if there is a better way to automate this for applications.

```css
#content-grid {
  margin: 27px 0px 50px 0px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 25%);
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  grid-row-gap: 0px;
  grid-column-gap: 0px;
  color: #D9D9D9;
}

#content-grid::before {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  grid-row: 1 / 1;
  grid-column: 1 / 1;
}

.item>p {
  margin: 35px;
  /*overflow: hidden;
 white-space: nowrap;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;*/
  color: black;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  font-size: .85em;
}

@media (max-width:950px) {
  #content-grid {
    grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="content-grid">
  <div class="item" style="background-color:#e6e6e6;">
    <h3>Theres Gonna Be a Heading Here, Too</h3>
    <p style="object-fit: cover;">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin iaculis vitae ligula in convallis. Aenean vitae lorem vitae nunc tristique maximus. Sed semper mauris leo, non congue felis ullamcorper non. Maecenas leo sapien, faucibus consequat ultricies
      eu, mollis vitae leo. Morbi quis tortor eu purus mattis viverra. Pellentesque gravida lectus turpis, iaculis ultricies nibh vestibulum volutpat. Donec placerat augue lorem, quis porta enim vehicula sed. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus
      et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris id consectetur magna. Aliquam interdum nisl elit, sit amet ultrices erat scelerisque nec. Aenean at felis lobortis, ultrices purus nec, iaculis tellus. Curabitur diam dolor, egestas sed iaculis
      cursus, vestibulum sed neque. Cras quis eleifend eros. Vestibulum est arcu, auctor et nisi vitae, malesuada maximus massa. Nam ut sodales nunc. Phasellus mauris sem, consequat sit amet enim ac, placerat consectetur arcu. Cras pellentesque arcu nec
      est finibus lobortis. Nunc et ligula libero. Nullam eget dolor non tellus commodo vulputate non at tortor. Nullam porta id ligula in placerat.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>
      There are several more divs, but they have very little text so the problem does not apply to them
    </p>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: You can try to using viewport sized topography. Check out this article: https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

Comment: Some ideas here - https://css-tricks.com/fitting-text-to-a-container/ I like the svg one but not sure if that text wraps - perhaps if you chose your breakpoints to start with?

Comment: My only concern with vw units is they don't appear to be supported by many browsers. I was hoping for a solution that would be a little more ubiquitous. [link](https://caniuse.com/#search=vw)

Answer (score -1):

Use word-break:break-all; property for the desired element, It will wrap the given element inside the parent div.
eg:

```
item>p{word-break:break-all;}
```